# Getting Syntax error using Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I keep getting a syntax error using Microsoft Access. I  believe I am putting in the iif statement incorrectly. I am even using the expression builder. However, it keeps saying that there may be a misplaced comma
[image]
Please help

Respectfully,

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  You should post the code rather than linking an image.

Answer (score 1):

In *Design View* instead of `,` use `;` in the `IIF()` function:

```
IIf([LastName]="Smith";1;0)
```

If you see the query in *SQL View* though, you will see the function with commas.
This is a case applying to regions where the comma could be a decimal separator (check your regional settings of your PC).

Comment: Expr1: IIf([lastname]="Smith";1;0)  .... it still saying synatx error. checked regional settings and they are fine.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your regional settings. You get an error because the `,` is not allowed in Design View. Switch to SQL View and write `SELECT orders.SubTotal, IIf([LastName]="Smith",1,0) AS Expr1 FROM orders;`. Then switch back to Design View and check the content of Expr1.

Comment: That Worked!! How would I get it to work in Design View?

Comment: When you switch back to design view from sql view, what is the expression?

Answer (score 0):

The error is not due to the use of the comma in place of a semi-colon, but rather because you have set the **Table** row to `Orders` within the query grid:

[image]

As such, the query is attempting to access a field called `[iif([LastName]="Smith",1,0)]` from the table `Orders`, and this is an invalid field name.

Since you are using a calculated field which isn't being sourced directly from any particular table, clear `Orders` from the table row for this field to fix the error.